# How to evaluate this double integral

Tags: integration

I need to evaluate the double integral

$$\iint \sqrt{3 - x^2 - y^2} \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \quad \text{over the upper half of the circle } x^2 + y^2 =x$$

Now, Using polar coordinates the given integral changes to:

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\cos\theta} \sqrt{3-r^2} \,r\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta $$

Integrating with respect to $r$ we get:

$$ \frac{3^{3/2} - (3 - \cos^2\theta)^{3/2}}{3}. $$

Now I am stuck. How should I integrate with respect to $\theta$?

Can anyone help me here?

Thank you

Comment: Actually, I meant to say upper half of the circle ie the portion of the circle above x-axis, I will make the edit in my question

Comment: The entire circle $x^2+y^2=y$ lies on and above the $x$-axis. Is the equation of the circle supposed to be $x^2+y^2=x$?

Comment: @ Sangchul Lee: Thanks for noticing that, yes the equation is $x^2 + y^2 =  x$

Comment: The integral over $(3-cos^2\theta)^{3/2}$ could not be done with elementary functions. It is of an elliptical integral.

Comment: @Quanto : So,there is no "Numerical" solution for this definite integral ?

Comment: You could always integrate numerically. But, you could not get an analytical result involving only elementary functions